# Let $A_{1}, \ldots, A_{d}$ be a covering of $\mathbb{S}^{d}$. Then $A_{i} \cap\left(-A_{i}\right) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: general-topology

Below is an alternative formulation of Borsuk Ulam theorem

(v) Let $A_{1}, \ldots, A_{d}$ be a covering of $\mathbb{S}^{d}$ by closed sets $A_{i} .$ Then there
exists i such that $A_{i} \cap\left(-A_{i}\right) \neq \emptyset$.

What does $(-A_i)$ means? i don't understand the meaning of the minus sign. Is it only saying take opposite of every element of $A$? i don't think so becvause then the statement seems false for $d=2$.

Comment: i can now see why it is true for d=2.  can someone please confirm what is (-A) just to be sure ? Thanks you!

Comment: How can you see that it is true for $d=2$ if you do not know what $-A$ means ;-)

Comment: @PaulFrost i conjectured it was what you wrote in your answer. :D thanks for response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$-A = \{- x \mid x \in A \}$. It is the image of $A$ under the antipodal map $f(x) = -x$.